# Is $A$ is connected in $\mathbb{R}^2?$ Yes/no

Tags: general-topology

Is  $A=(\{0\} \times \mathbb{R} ) \cup (\{1\}\times  \mathbb{R} )$ is connected in $\mathbb{R}^2?$

My attempt :I think $A$ is connected

$\mathbb{R}$ is homeomorphic to $\{0\}\times \mathbb{R}$ because there is the homeomorphism$$\begin{array}{ccc}\mathbb{R}&\longrightarrow&\{0\}\times \mathbb{R}\\y&\mapsto&(0,y).\end{array}$$

$\mathbb{R}$ is homeomorphic to $\{1\}\times \mathbb{R}$ because there is the homeomorphism$$\begin{array}{ccc}\mathbb{R}&\longrightarrow&\{1\}\times \mathbb{R}\\y&\mapsto&(1,y).\end{array}$$

$$(\{0\} \times \mathbb{R} ) \cup (\{1\}\times  \mathbb{R} \cong \mathbb{R} \cup \mathbb{R}$$

$\implies A$ is connected

Comment: $A$ has 2 subspaces that are both homeomorphic to $R$, but that doesn't mean $A$ is connected.

Comment: To give you a hint: can you draw $A$ without lifting up your pencil? The answer, at least in this case, will be the same as whether $A$ is connected.

Comment: Have you drawn $A$?

Comment: Your argument basically says "a union of two connected sets is connected."  But, that is false by thinking of small examples like $(0,1) \cup (2,3)$.

Comment: @Randall if we draw A ,then both subspace will connected by segement $0$ to $1$ on $x $axis

Comment: No, they're not.  That segment is not a part of $A$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$A$ is indeed the union of two subsets each one homeomorphic to $\mathbb R$... but this is not a reason for $A$ to be connected.

In fact $A$ is the disjoint union of two open subsets for the induced topology from $\mathbb R^2$ and is therefore not connected.

$$A= (\{0\} \times \mathbb R \cap (-\infty,1/2)\times \mathbb R) \cup (\{1\} \times \mathbb R \cap (1/2, \infty)\times \mathbb R)$$

Answer (score 2):

Observe that $\{0\}\times\mathbb{R}$ and $\{1\}\times\mathbb{R}$ are both relatively open in $A$, non-empty and disjoint. Therefore, $A$ is disconnected.

Answer (score 1):

Your set $A$ is not connected; in fact, as you've noticed, it consists in two (disjoint) copies of $\Bbb R$ "inside" $\Bbb R^2$.
This does not mean that $A\cong\Bbb R$ (it is not, in fact, the case).

Each of the two lines $\{0\}\times\Bbb R$ and $\{1\}\times\Bbb R$ is a closed subspace of $\Bbb R^2$, and hence they are closed subspaces of $A$ (why?); $A$ is the union of the two, so you can safely conclude that $A$ is disconnected (and the two lines are its connected components, since they're both connected spaces).

Comment: I don't know what's your definition of connectedness, but your counterexample seems disconnected to me. The two components just happen to have zero distance.

Comment: I don't understand what part of the answer you are contesting. Are you arguing that $\{(x,0)\mid x\in\Bbb R\}\cup \{(x,1/x)\mid x>0\}$ is a connected subset of $\Bbb R^2$?

Comment: ...Are you suggesting that closed disjoint subsets of a topological space $X$ are not closed and/or disjoint for the topology induced on their union?
Isn't that the definition of induced topology itself?

Comment: ...Either you're arguing that disjoint subsets are not disjoint anymore when you change topology (which is nonsense), or that for a closed set $F\subseteq X$ and $Y\subseteq X$, $F\cap Y$ isn't necessarily closed in $Y$ with the subspace topology (which contradicts the definition of subspace topology). Which one are you implying?

Comment: The claim is that the statement "two disjoint closed subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$ has a disconnected union" is false.  There is a difference between being closed in the plane and being closed in the subspace topology of the union.  The example given by @mathcounterexamples.net shows why.

Comment: Sorry, I still fail to see how these $A$ and $B$ could ever be not closed in the subspace topology. What kind of definitions are we working with? Isn't a set closed in the subspace topology _iff_ it is the intersection of a closed set with the subspace itself?

Comment: (Also: let $f(x)$ be $\frac{1}{2x}$ for $x>1$, and $\frac12$ for $x\leq 1$. The two open sets $\{(x,y)\mid y<f(x)\}$ and $\{(x,y)\mid y>f(x)\}$ of $\Bbb R^2$ make respectively $A$ and $B$ disjoint open sets in $A\cup B$ with the subspace topology.)

Comment: @Ottavio I was wrong. The $A$ and $B$ in my comments are indeed connected. I’ll delete my wrong comments above. Sorry for this!

Comment: @Ottavio  I also figured out my own mistakes/interpretations!  Sorry.